# Shiny Dashboard: Sticky Footer in dashboardSidebar

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a Shiny Dashboard with a footer in the `dashboardSidebar`, that is sticky to the bottom of the viewport. For this, I am trying to use custom CSS styling as suggested [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css) (one of many search results when Googling "footer bottom bootstrap") :

```
# create an example for the SO question on sticky footer
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# sidebar
so_sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      text = "Some text."
    )
  ),
  # footer here
  tags$footer(
    tags$p("Footer message here."), 
    style = "
      * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
  }
  .footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
  }

  /*

  Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
  http://ryanfait.com/

  */"
  )

)

# compose the dashboard
so_ui = dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = "SO question"
  ), 
  sidebar = so_sidebar, 
  body = dashboardBody()
)

# run the application
shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = so_ui, 
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
)
```

Since I have never worked with custom CSS before, I am not sure I am using the CSS right. I am following the instructions [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

Can someone help with getting this CSS right, or with any other suggestions on a footer that is sticky to the bottom of the viewable area in the sidebar of a Shiny Dashboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w2ofqvg4/)

```
 <div>
    Sticky Footer
</div> 

div{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  background:#00adfc;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Position fixed always stay at the specified position and gives a sticky feel.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this is not Shiny specific, and I do not know how to implement this. Shiny is an R framework for generating HTML code by writing R code.

Comment: Actually, I got this to work with Shiny -- I will update the Shiny code in the question and mark this right. I have another question though. How can I also get an image above this text that is also anchored to the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: In a R style you can add the css into a css file in `www/` folder by creating a css class for example `.sticky_footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   background:#3c8dbc;
   z-index: 1000;
   opacity: 0.9;
}`. Then, you can add the `div` in `dashboardBody`: `div(class = "sticky_footer", p("test footer"))`